# Connecting Scarlett Solo output to mixer in live setting

Tags: ableton-live, audio, mixer

I would like to play virtual instruments in Ableton Live in rehearsal setting. At my disposal are:

- Scarlett Solo interface ([with stereo RCA outputs](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41HBQZq7zgL.jpg))
- laptop with Ableton Live
- Mackie Fx Pro 12 mixer

Mixer offers 1/4 inch line ins per each channel and few RCA labeled "unbalanced" - I am not sure what this means in this situtation.

[image]

Question: How do I connect interface to mixer, in order to hear interface output in the monitors?

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: I can't figure out what you mean by "columns", by the way. That's not a term normally used to describe a part of an audio mixer.

Comment: "Columns" would be local word for "monitor speakers". Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Interesting. Old people like me would be likely to call monitor speakers "wedges", since they used to be almost always wedge-shaped speaker cabinets on the floor. I guess a lot of people now use the new style of column speakers that Bose invented.

Comment: Here (in Poland) word "kolumna" _singular_ / "kolumny" _plural_ is used loosely to mention various specialized and/or high end speakers of considerable power. And most likely it stems from popularization of the standard mentioned by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those red and white outputs on the back of the Scarlett Solo are called ***RCA jacks***. In the case of the Scarlett, those jacks are outputs. You can connect them to any *RCA inputs* using an RCA cable.

This is what an RCA cable looks like:

[image]

Get an RCA cable and connect it to the outputs of the Scalett, matching the red plug to the red jack and the white plug to the white jack. Plug the other end of the cable (white to white and red to red) into the left side of the group of four RCA jacks on the Mackie. That's the side the says "Tape In" to the left of the jacks.

Now look at the main fader, which is the one farthest to the right. Right above the main fader is a knob labelled "Tape Level". Play sound from your computer and turn the "Tape Level" knob slowly to the right until you hear the volume you want.

<sup>Image source: https://pisces.bbystatic.com/image2/BestBuy_US/images/products/4408/4408065_sa.jpg;maxHeight=640;maxWidth=550</sup>